# Ubuntu web browser app crashes on execution

Tags: 16.04, webbrowser-app

I'm using 16.04 and whenever I try to open Browser app, it crashes. 
I've tried uninstall/reinstall the app but the problem still remains.

Here is the output when I run `webbrowser-app` via terminal:

```
(webbrowser-app:29022): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:29022): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.

(webbrowser-app:29022): dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create file '/run/user/1000/dconf/user': Permission denied.  dconf will not work properly.
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/ContentPickerDialog.qml:22:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/ContentDownloadDialog.qml:22:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/ContentHandler.qml:20:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed
file:///usr/share/webbrowser-app/webbrowser/DownloadHandler.qml:20:1: module "Ubuntu.DownloadManager" is not installed
Input device added: "Power Button" "/dev/input/event2" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Video Bus" "/dev/input/event5" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Power Button" "/dev/input/event0" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Video Bus" "/dev/input/event4" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "Lid Switch" "/dev/input/event1" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: " 2.4G RF MOUSE" "/dev/input/event6" QFlags(0x2)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH Mic" "/dev/input/event9" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH Headphone" "/dev/input/event10" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3" "/dev/input/event11" QFlags(0x20)
Input device added: "Ideapad extra buttons" "/dev/input/event8" QFlags(0x1)
Input device added: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" "/dev/input/event3" QFlags(0x1|0x10)
Input device added: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad" "/dev/input/event7" QFlags(0x4|0x8)
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior 2, swapInterval 1, profile  0) 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Launch the browser from terminal. It should print log messages into the terminal window. Edit your question and paste these messages to it.

Comment: @Melebius I updated my question

Comment: I have a similar problem here (abbreviated because of comment limit):  
---
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader
QOpenGLShader: could not create shader