# How do I get the Reminders app to work?

Tags: qml

I installed the Reminders app on Ubuntu Xenial (not Ubuntu Touch):

```
sudo apt install reminders-app
```

It doesn't seem to start correctly:

```
Running against the production server
using main qml file from: "/usr/share/reminders/qml/reminders.qml"
virtual void OnlineAccountsClient::Plugin::registerTypes(const char*) Ubuntu.OnlineAccounts.Client
file:///usr/share/reminders/qml/reminders.qml:312:23: Type NotesPage unavailable 
                     page: NotesPage { 
                           ^
file:///usr/share/reminders/qml/ui/NotesPage.qml:41:30: Type EditNotePage unavailable 
         bottomEdgePageComponent: EditNotePage { 
                                  ^
file:///usr/share/reminders/qml/ui/EditNotePage.qml:37:5: Type EditNoteView unavailable 
         EditNoteView { 
         ^
file:///usr/share/reminders/qml/ui/EditNoteView.qml:24:1: module "Ubuntu.Content" is not installed 
     import Ubuntu.Content 0.1 
     ^
```

How do I get it to **start correctly?** I think I am missing one of the `qml-module-ubuntu-*` packages but I don't know which one.

Comment: This might be related but it's a different app: https://askubuntu.com/questions/813355/ubuntu-web-browser-app-crashes-on-execution

Comment: According to [this page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/xenial/amd64/reminders-app/filelist) the missing EditNotePage and NotesPage ought to be installed in `/usr/share/reminders/qml/ui/`. Is there anything in that directory?

Comment: @Jos sure, some of the files in that directory are giving errors (see the output lines starting with `file:///`).